# Package Drive Connect Install Failed

Tags: api, integration, appexchange

I'm having this problem while trying to install Drive Connect in my Sandbox env.

Your request to install package "Drive Connect 2.85" was unsuccessful. None of the data or setup information in your salesforce.com organization was affected.

If your install continues to fail, contact Salesforce CRM Support through your normal channels and provide the following information.

Problem:

1. Missing Organization Feature: ApiAndPlatformEvents
   null
2. Missing Organization Feature: ApiAndHighVolumePlatformEvents
   null

How do I enable ApiAndPlatformEvents and ApiAndHighVolumePlatformEvents in my Org?

Comment: Is the edition of your org something other than Enterprise or Unlimited?

Comment: You need to have 'API enabled' set to true in your org to be able to install the package. See [Salesforce editions with API access](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326486&type=1)